# Is there a way to use django's built-in user authentication in Google app engine (Python)?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, authentication

I understand that Google App Engine has it's own user authentication facilities but it offers only three possible way to authenticate:

- A Google Account
- An account on your Google Apps domain
- An OpenID identifier

But what I want is to have the same power that Django's django.contrib.auth gives, with permissions and groups with internal user database. Is there a way to have this Django module ported and used in Google app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use non-rel to run Django on App Engine.

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html